# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheet' of undefined

Tags: function, google-sheets, count, cell

Im attempting to add a custom formula to a G Sheet where I can count the number of cells with a specific background color within a certain range. I keep receiving different errors, but the most recent error has been "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheet' of undefined".

Formula here for reference:

```js
function countColoredCells(countRange,colorRef) {
    var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange[(1576162255)];
    var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet('External Payment Requests!');
    var formula = activeRange.getFormula();

    var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/((.*),/).pop();
    var range = activeSheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
    var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
    var values = range.getValues();

    var colorCellA1Notation = formula.match(/,(.*))/).pop();
    var colorCell = activeSheet.getRange(colorCellA1Notation);
    var color = colorCell.getBackground();

    var count = 0;

    for(var i=0;i<bg.length;i++)
        for(var j=0;j<bg[0].length;j++)
            if( bg[i][j] == color )
                count=count+1;
    
    return count;
};
```

I've tried adding the exact name of the sheet in hopes that this would allow the function, but I keep receiving the same error, whether the get.sheet field is blank or not.

Comment: it is much more common to use the *reason* the cells have been colored instead of the *fact* that they are colored.
Are there identifiable reasons that you've colored certain cells the colors that they are?

Comment: This spreadsheet is used to monitor chat misuse. Our team takes the results of a blazer query, then places them within the sheet.  I added conditional formatting to color certain cells that contained keywords (ex: "dry ice" converts cells from white to yellow, "tobacco" would be red etc.)

Comment: Understood.  so counting all the cells that contain "dry ice" would be much simpler than counting the yellow cells.